# Firebase console create dynamic link error

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to create a dynamic link in the firebase web console but I'm getting this error:

`An error occurred when creating a new Dynamic Link`

If I inspect in the developer console I can see this error.

`{code: 400, message: "Request contains an invalid argument.", status: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"}`

Comment: Did you added dependency for Firebase Dynamic Links to your app level ?

Comment: This is not in my app. It's in the firebase web console.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to include the deep link you're trying to add to your [Whitelist URL patterns](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429). That will fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks, that wasn't very obvious by the error message provided :P

Comment: This is so unintuitive. Everyone will go through this post lol..

Comment: Over three years later. Same error message, whitelisting doesn't help.