# Whitelist domain for firebase web app in google cloud

Tags: firebase-authentication

When running an application in localhost and sending a registration verification email, there is a 400 error from `identitytoolkit.googleapis.com` saying `UNAUTHORIZED_DOMAIN : Domain not whitelisted by project`.

Indeed, this works from my firebase-hosted app, but not from localhost. For testing purposes, I'd like to be able to send verification emails from localhost as well, (and perhaps from a testing project later). How do I whitelist the localhost domain in my google cloud project?

Assuming this doesn't go against security good practice.

Is it even possible to achieve from localhost?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70995132/3006011). Basically, we also have to whitelist (inside firebase console) the url passed into `sendEmailVerification()`.